# extend a symfony bundle command

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, symfony-console

For a project, I am using the league/oauth2-server-bundle. This bundle has a command `league:oauth:create-client` that creates a client in the database.

In this project, I have a ClientConfiguration entity linked to the bundle's Client entity, which allows adding additional configuration.

I would like to be able to "extend" the bundle's create-client command. I want to keep all the options and arguments configuration from the base CreateClientCommand class to create the client but also add options for the additional configuration.

I can't directly extends the CreateClientCommand from the bundle because it's a final class.

i tried by injecting the base command and copy it's definition in my new command

```
class CreateClientWithConfiguration extends Command {


    function __construct(private readonly CreateClientCommand $createClientCommand)
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setDefinition($this->createClientCommand->getDefinition());
        $this->setDescription('This create a new oAuth client with additionnal configuration')
            ->setName('oauth:create-client-configuration')
            // add custom options
            ;

    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $options = [];
        foreach($input->getOptions() as $key => $option){
            $options["--".$key] = $option;
        }

        $arrayInput = array_merge(['command' => 'league:oauth:create-client'],$input->getArguments(),$options);

        $createClientInput = new ArrayInput($arrayInput);
    
        $returnCode = $this->getApplication()->doRun($createClientInput, $output);

        // do other stuffs
     }
}
```

but the `$options` array contains all options like --version and it's automatically detected when using doRun() even if the option value is off and it directly stop the execution :

```
    public function doRun(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if (true === $input->hasParameterOption(['--version', '-V'], true)) {
            $output->writeln($this->getLongVersion());

            return 0;
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Is there a clean way to do this without manually copy the arguments and options of CreateClientCommand ?

Comment: Try calling the `execute()` method instead; even if it's protected, it will be allowed as both instances are children of the same parent https://3v4l.org/hAU8q.

Comment: @yceruto i don't understand your answer. As i said my command does not extends CreateClientCommand from the bundle because it cannot it's a final class..

Comment: The best way to achieve this is to "decorate" the original command https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to manually create the options and arguments array that you pass to the create-client command. Of course, this means that whenever the "base command" adds a new option or argument, then you will have to update your code, but maybe that doesn't happen that often.

Comment: That's what i ended to do. Thank you.